# How to update a QTextEdit in real-time

Tags: python, pyqt, qtextedit

i have one UI with QtextEdit,
(1) i want to update QtextEdit and main UI can display realtime and no stuck.   when use sleep ,not work as i want.
(2) i want have make one function and pass parameter to it, and the QtestEdit can update display real time

```
self.pButton_torun.clicked.connect(self.mytodo)

 def mytodo(self):
        self.progress_textEdit.append(u"==== 20 % first step finish")
        #after 2 sec
        self.progress_textEdit.append(u"==== 40 % second step finish")
        #after 2 sec
        self.progress_textEdit.append(u"==== 60 % third step finish")
        #after 2 sec
        self.progress_textEdit.append(u"==== 80 % forth step finish")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `processEvents()`:

```
def mytodo(self):
    self.progress_textEdit.append(u"==== 20 % first step finish")
    QApplication.processEvents()
    # etc...
```

This is a bit of a workaround though, down the track you might also want to consider using separate threads.

Comment: self.main_app means QtextEdit ?

Comment: `self.main_app` would be your `QApplication`, or a class that extends it.

Comment: The function is static, so do: `QApplication.processEvents()`.