# How to create a loading progress bar like we see in Photoshop with PySide,PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

This is my code. Iam trying to show a progress bar that shows the loading status till all the widgets are properly loaded but the progress bar wont update properly.It only updates in the end of the process and shows 100%

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
import time
import sys
class Mainwindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.progress = QProgressBar()
        self.progress.setRange(0, 100)
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.worker.relay.connect(self.update_progress)
        self.thread.start()
        self.progress.show()
        self.add_tabs()

    def add_tabs(self):
        for i in xrange(10000):
            i*i
        time.sleep(1)
        self.worker.process()

        for i in xrange(10000):
            i*i
        time.sleep(1)
        self.worker.process()

        for i in xrange(10000):
            i*i
        time.sleep(1)
        self.worker.process()

        for i in xrange(10000):
            i*i
        time.sleep(1)
        self.worker.process()

        for i in xrange(10000):
            i*i
        time.sleep(1)
        self.worker.process()

        for i in xrange(10000):
            i*i
        time.sleep(1)
        self.worker.process()

        for i in xrange(10000):
            i*i
        time.sleep(1)
        self.worker.process()

        for i in xrange(10000):
            i*i
        time.sleep(1)
        self.worker.process()

        for i in xrange(10000):
            i*i
        time.sleep(1)
        self.worker.process()

        for i in xrange(10000):
            i*i
        time.sleep(1)
        self.worker.process()

    @Slot(int)
    def update_progress(self, x):
        self.progress.setValue(x * 10)

class Worker(QObject):
    relay = Signal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Worker, self).__init__(parent)
        self.x = 0

    def process(self):
        while self.x < 10:
            self.x = self.x+1
            self.relay.emit(self.x)
            print self.x
            return True

if __name__=='__main__':
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    win=Mainwindow()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
    sys.exit(0)
```

**Edit 1**
It is claimed that my question is a duplicate of [how to make QtextEdit can update data realtime and no stuck UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581126/how-to-make-qtextedit-can-update-data-realtime-and-no-stuck-ui) but i have tried process events, process events are for loops or the process we do in the front end. In my case those loops you see with xrange are backend processes in my real program. The xrange loops were used here to have an understanding, that i have real backend tasks running for which i cannot use process events. Sorry for not making myself clear in the first place. I need a Qthread based solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make QtextEdit can update data realtime and no stuck UI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581126/how-to-make-qtextedit-can-update-data-realtime-and-no-stuck-ui)

Comment: @figs I have tried that but it wont work if you have large backend tasks to be done.

Comment: Not a duplicate but a similar question I answered few weeks ago: [Use a Progress Bar in a GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480097/use-a-progress-bar-in-a-gui/30486099?noredirect=1#comment49052939_30486099)
 Maybe this can give you some clues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to do some heavy processing on a separate thread and update the progress on the main GUI. So all the processing done in `MainWindow.add_tabs` should actually be done in the worker.

Also, it seems like you want to use `QProgressDialog`(pop-up window) instead of `QProgressBar`.

Here's a solution, with a responsive GUI:

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
import time
import sys

class Mainwindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.worker.workRequested.connect(self.thread.start)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.add_tabs)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.on_finish)

        self.button=QPushButton("Add tabs")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_button_click)

        self.button_responsive=QPushButton("Still responsive?")
        self.button_responsive.clicked.connect(self.responsive)

        self.progress = QProgressDialog("Progress","cancel",0,10)
        self.progress.setCancelButton(None)
        self.worker.relay.connect(self.update_progress)

        vbox=QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.button)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button_responsive)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def on_button_click(self):
        self.button.setEnabled(False)
        self.worker.request_work()
        self.progress.setValue(0)

    def on_finish(self):
        self.button.setEnabled(True)
        self.thread.quit()

    def update_progress(self,value):
        self.progress.setValue(value)

    def responsive(self):
        print("Yes!")


class Worker(QObject):
    workRequested=Signal()
    finished=Signal()
    relay=Signal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Worker, self).__init__(parent)
        self.x = 0

    def request_work(self):
        self.workRequested.emit()

    def add_tabs(self):
        self.x=0
        for i in range(10):
            #Do any processing
            for i in xrange(10000):
                i*i
            time.sleep(1)
            self.x+=1
            self.relay.emit(self.x)
        self.finished.emit()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    win=Mainwindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: it is working well but unfortunately my process also needs to update the gui which is not advisable to be done outside the main thread.
**ps**: iam really sorry for the late reply

Comment: The Worker can send various signals to update the gui. In my code, the worker emit the signal `relay`, and the gui update the progress bar. What's your problem ?

Comment: well let me be little long in explaination:
the mainwindow has a tab widget,
each process imports a module which has a widgets and its functions which is added to the tab widget.
now updating the tabwidget seems an issue.the errors
`QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QApplication(0x9c99580), parent's thread is QThread(0x86d4b38), current thread is QThread(0xa347050)`

Comment: I suggest posting a new question, as this problem is unrelated to the progress bar.

Comment: i wanted updating progressbar while these modules were updated...that was the question isn't it?

Comment: The error you have above in unrelated to the progress bar. Your new problem is  "I want to update/load some module in a thread, an have this error message". You cant' expect people to answer this problem if your question title is "How to create a loading progress bar"

Comment: "how to create a loading progress bar" is the short form of the question and the expanded version of the question is available for understanding my problem. And the error that i mentioned in the comment was after following your code, which was really good but one cannot update a mainwindow in a thread.

Comment: forget everything else, i worked on your suggestions, and made up my solution. It would have not been possible if you would have not suggested. Accepted your version.